# Ubuntu - switch keyboard layout to Colemak

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, colemak

So I am trying to relearn Colemak and am using Ubuntu 10.04. I go up to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layout, click Add, find USA Colemak, and add it.

When I try it out in the "Type to test settings" box, it is still in Qwerty, and if I apply it system-wide my system is still using Qwerty. Does anyone else have this problem or have any suggestions?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate in the ubuntu community. At the far bottom of this page you should see a list of related communities and ubuntu is there.

Comment: Sorry, @Hanmyo, this site is intended just for programming questions.  This question might fit better on superuser.com or askubuntu.com

Answer (score 16):

Try opening a terminal and copy and paste this:

```
setxkbmap us -variant colemak
```

You might also want to try to changing the keyboard layout on the login screen.

Comment: Looks like this doesn’t save over reboots. Or maybe my ubuntu is losing settings (its a bit buggy after the 17.04 update)

Answer (score 2):

You need to click `Move Up` so it is at the top of the list of layouts. Then it should take effect.

Comment: Also yuo can switch forward/backward the layouts with keys (default Super+Space and Shift*Super+Space)